# How to get 80% random elements from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list with integers. I want to choose `80%` from them.
For example, for `[1,...,30]` I want to keep 80% from the list with `random` so I get for example `[1,...,32]\[3,7,19,21,25,29]` (It means it deleted `3,7,19,21,25,29` values from the original list. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Did you tried doing `random.shuffle()` on your list and slice it based on 80% of the length?

Answer (score 4):

```py
import random

random.sample(lst, k=round(len(lst) * 0.8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is a.

You can use random.sample() to select samples from the list

```py
a = [1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,4,5]
percent = 80/100
total_length = len(a)
print(random.sample(a,k=int(percent*total_length)))
#k is the number to be sampled (in your case 80% of total length)
```